# ClientContext.executeQuery() throws operation Timeout error

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, error, time-out, httpcontext

Trying to create a list item in the SharePoint list in a batch of 5 using Visual Studio but the `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` throws exception and only create 1 list item.

```
var url = "calling a webservice";
var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);
JsonResultInfo jsri = new JsonResultInfo();
List<JsonResult> dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(content);
```

//Connect to SharePoint and read Idea list

- List item

  CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
      string siteUrl = "sharepoint site list url";
      ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
      SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LIST NAME");
      ListItemCollection listItems = oList.GetItems(query);
      clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;
      clientContext.Load(listItems);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();|
      oListItem["title] = item.title;
      oListItem["body"] = item.body;
      oListItem.Update();
       itemCount++;

get itemcount to 5 , then

`clientContext.ExecuteQuery();` // the execption is thrown saying
 A first chance exception of type '`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException'` occurred in

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

ps: Added Request timeout , and gave this exception

Answer (score 1):

Please increase RequestTimeOut of ClientContext as shown below:

```
clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi, i added it. it thrw another error "A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
". i have modified the question. kindly help!

Comment: Didn't understood please elaborate more in details

Comment: You will need to put  clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); after each item update.because SharePoint didn't understood currently which item going to update.

Comment: i am pulling the data from a web service and comparing the data present in the share point  and which ever data that is not present in share point list , is added to the list as a new item.

Comment: still throwing  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException